# Не работает тестовый код pyttsx3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Не работает тестовый код `pyttsx3`

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

При установке `pyttsx3` ошибок не было `pypiwin32` и `piwin32` установлны также без ошибок

Запуская файл через cmd и он мгновенно закрывается

Windows 10 1909
Python 3.8

Comment: Через IDLE Python пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо, через идол все заработоло, но в чем проблема когда я запускаю через cmd&

Comment: Как вы запускаете покажите скриншот

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/135tO8oMaOsUI-pFVMdS7y6qZ2r3UN5i0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MinuteX Запускайте так `python name.py`.

Answer (score 0):

*Попробуйте так и посмотрите* **log.txt**

```
import pyttsx3


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    with open("log.txt", "w") as log:
        log.write(text)

 sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


def main():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say("Hello!")
    engine.runAndWait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```